# Why does the value not change to false in AuthGuard?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular6

In the template component `AppComponent`, depending on the value, the variable `this.loggedInService.isLoggedIn` switches between the `logIn()` and `logout()` methods, which in the application component `AppComponent` are `subscribe`d to these methods in the service `LoggedinService`and depending on the method, change the value of the variable to `true` or `false`.

Also in the Guard's method `checkLogin (url: string)` I return `true` or `false` depending on the value of the variable `this.loggedInService.isLoggedIn`.

**When I start the application, I cannot enter the module, when I click on the button, I can, but when I repeat click on the button "exit", I can still go to the module.**

How to make the switch to `checkLogin` work so that the authentication works correctly and save the value of switching the state between input and output when the page is restarted?

**AppComponent.html: **

```
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="btn btn-outline-success"
               [class.btn-outline-success]="!this.loggedInService.isLoggedIn$"
               [class.btn-outline-danger]="this.loggedInService.isLoggedIn$"
               (click)="this.loggedInService.isLoggedIn$ ? logout() : logIn()">
                {{this.loggedInService.isLoggedIn$ ? 'Exit' : 'Enter'}}
            </a>
        </li>
```

**AppComponent.ts **

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    message: string;

```
constructor(public loggedInService: LoggedinService,
            public router: Router) {
    this.setMessage();
}

ngOnInit() {}

logIn(): void {
    this.loggedInService.login().subscribe(() => {
        if (this.loggedInService.isLoggedIn$) {
            let redirect = this.loggedInService.redirectUrl ? this.loggedInService.redirectUrl :
                '/gallery';
            this.router.navigate([redirect]);
        }
    });
}

logout(): void {
    this.loggedInService.logout();
}
```

}

**LoggedinService:**

```
export class LoggedinService {
isLoggedIn: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
isLoggedIn$: Observable<boolean> = this.isLoggedIn.asObservable();
  redirectUrl: string;

  constructor() {}

  login(): Observable < boolean > {
    return of(true).pipe(
      delay(100),
      tap(val => this.isLoggedIn.next(true))
    );
  }

  logout(): void {
    this.isLoggedIn.next(false);
  }
}
```

**AuthGuard:**

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private loggedInService: LoggedinService, 
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    let url: string = state.url;
    return this.loggedInService.isLoggedIn$;
  }

  checkLogin(url: string): boolean {
    if (this.loggedInService.isLoggedIn) {
      return true;
    } else {
      this.loggedInService.redirectUrl = url;
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a single service instance in the whole application? In a nutshell, did you add `LoggedinService` to your main module's providers and **did not** Include the service in the components providers? Otherwise, multiple service instances will be created.

Comment: I have two services for the whole application and they are connected to "app.module" in "providers"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isLoggedIn` in your `LoggedinService` is a Primitive Data type. So it is not passed by reference. It's passed by value. So if there is a change in it at one place, the same change won't reflect at other places where it is used.

This behavior is only exhibited by Objects as they are passed by reference and NOT value.

You could use a `BehaviorSubject` to fix this issue.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { delay, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class LoggedinService {

  isLoggedIn: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  isLoggedIn$: Observable<boolean> = this.isLoggedIn.asObservable();
  redirectUrl: string;

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  login(): Observable<boolean> {
    this.isLoggedIn.next(true);
    return this.isLoggedIn$;
  }

  logout(): Observable<boolean> {
    this.isLoggedIn.next(false);
    return this.isLoggedIn$;
  }

}
```

Now, instead of `isLoggedIn` of type `boolean`, you'll get `isLoggedIn$` of type `Observable` which you'll have to `subscribe` to, to get the logged in status of the user.

You'll have to `.subscribe` to `this.loggedInService.login()` and `this.loggedInService.login()` in your AppComponent as both of them return `isLoggedIn$`. You'll have to create a local `isLoggedIn` property and assign it whatever is returned in your `.subscribe`. You can then set the button text and click handler based on the template based on this `isLoggedIn` property.

In the case, of AuthGuard, since a guard can return `Observable<boolean>` or `Promise<boolean>` or `boolean`, you can simply `return this.loggedInService.isLoggedIn$`

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-route-guards) for your ref.

Comment: Where to subscribe  in "app.ts" or "authGuard"?
could not explain this moment more detailed

Comment: I changed as you said, but now nothing works (there are no errors)

Comment: @IgorShvets, I've updated the answer. Please check if that helps. I've also added a stackblitz for your ref.